# cocoa webview links disabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

On OSX, I am using XCode to make a desktop app with a webview in it. The webview loads ok, and I can dynamically load content into it - but when I click on links inside the webview, they are not followed. They change color, but no new page is loaded. If I code my links with javascript like this - then they work.

```
<a href='http://x/' onClick="window.location = this.href">link there</a>
```

Is there an Objective-C one liner that allows links to be followed inside web-views?

Is there another issue I am not aware of here?

Comment: If I load gmail into a webview, I can use the emails, compose etc... but the links at the top don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had code I copied form the web with some custom function to ignore WebPolicyDecisionListener...

Sorry for asking question without giving all the details - all this objective-c is new to me, I don't know which bits do what yet. I do some pointing and clicking, and then some coding - I don't know exactly how that all links up. With other languages, you have the whole program in one place - it takes a bit of a learning curve to get used to... but I digress.

I fixed by adding some comments - see code below...

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)aWebView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request 
          frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    if ([self requestIsLinkClick:actionInformation]) {
        if ([@"method" isEqual:[[request URL] scheme]]) {
            SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([[request URL] resourceSpecifier]);
            if ([prototypeDelegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
                [prototypeDelegate performSelector:selector];
            }
        }
        // [listener ignore];
    } // else {
        [listener use];
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The links at the top of Gmail open in a new window. To make them work you have to implement at least the [`WebUIDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods `webView:createWebViewWithRequest:` and `webViewShow:`. If you simply want to open all links in the same web view, you could return it from `webView:createWebViewWithRequest:` instead of creating a new one.